# Subscribe to DisplayAlert in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: testing, xamarin.forms, alert, messaging

I'd like to get notified whenever `DisplayAlert` is called somewhere in my app. The [Xamarin.Forms source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L142) suggests to use the `MessagingCenter`, since it is using it to send a message within `DisplayAlert()`:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, AlertSignalName, args);
```

But I haven't been able to receive anything, yet. This is one of the lines I tried so far:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, Page.AlertSignalName, arg => {
    Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + arg);
});
```

Is this the right direction? Or do you have an alternative solution? I'd even consider some hacky reflection-based approach, since I need it for testing purposes only.

Comment: Interesting. Never tried... Does not work your approach?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro No, I tried to vary `Page` and `Page.AlertSignalName`, but the delegate never got called.

Comment: I take a look. I promise nothing...

Comment: AlertArguments used is not available to consume,I suggest you don't use DisplayAlert but instead create MyDisplayAlert. In this function call Display alert and use your own Send call

Comment: @YuriS I'm working on a library for testing Xamarin.Forms apps. Thus, if somehow possibly, I'd rather stick with `DisplayAlert` to be compatible with any app without any adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.AlertArguments>(this, Page.AlertSignalName, (obj, obj1) => {
    int aa = 0;
});
```

But it is raised when `DisplayAlert` is displayed. (I think it's correct...)

This is my page:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage()
        {
            Button b = new Button {Text = "Press" };
            b.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                await DisplayAlert("Attention", "AAA", "Ok");
                MessagingCenter.Send<MyPage>(this, "AAA");
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" },
                    b
                }
            };

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage>(this, "AAA", (obj) => {
                int aa = 0;
            });
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.AlertArguments>(this, Page.AlertSignalName, (obj, obj1) => {
                int aa = 0;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the source code of XFroms included? I am getting "The type or namespace name 'AlertArguments' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Internals' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" AlertArguments is not public

Comment: nothing... If you cut and paste the code, it should works. Have you XF updated?

Comment: All latest  and Falko gets the same result

Comment: Yes, latest stable 2.3.4.247. I get the same compiler error like Yuri S.

Comment: And what happens? Which delegate is executed? You're subscribing twice. So probably it's `MessagingCenter.Send<MyPage>(this, "AAA");` what you're receiving.

Comment: If he is able to compile he should get both but I am wondering how it is compiled. XForms should be different than ours with @Falco

Comment: @Falko I received two... put a breakpoint in the second int aa = 0; and it stop there

Comment: I figured this out. @AlessandroCaliaro is using XForms 2.3.5.239 Pre-3. Can you confirm?

Comment: @YuriS Oh, very interesting! Maybe this pull request was the crucial change between 2.3.4 and 2.3.5-pre1: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/782. I'll try it out tomorrow and probably accept this answer. I guess it's not worth to search for a workaround for the current stable 2.3.4, before 2.3.5 comes out in a few weeks.

Comment: I would wait till stable release and not spend time on workaround if you don't want to use your custom Send which BTW would work from library too if you specify all your members as public and not like Xamarin internal :-)

Comment: BTW, my method will protect your library if Xamarin decides to change arguments or hide them again

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin [source test code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core.UnitTests/PageTests.cs) (namespace `Xamarin.Forms.Core.UnitTests`), it's used in a strongly typed way like that:

```
[Test]
public void DisplayAlert ()
{
    var page = new ContentPage ();

    AlertArguments args = null;
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe (this, Page.AlertSignalName, (Page sender, AlertArguments e) => args = e);

    var task = page.DisplayAlert ("Title", "Message", "Accept", "Cancel");

    Assert.AreEqual ("Title", args.Title);
    Assert.AreEqual ("Message", args.Message);
    Assert.AreEqual ("Accept", args.Accept);
    Assert.AreEqual ("Cancel", args.Cancel);

    bool completed = false;
    var continueTask = task.ContinueWith (t => completed = true);

    args.SetResult (true);
    continueTask.Wait ();
    Assert.True (completed);
}
```

So this should do it:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, Page.AlertSignalName, (Page sender, AlertArguments args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + args.Message);
});
```

Comment: Please see the comment about AlertArguments in other answer

Comment: As @YuriS mentions: `AlertArguments` is not accessible due to its `internal` protection level.

Comment: Hmm my bad sorry I was writing at the same time... Very interesting by the way!